# Probability distributions and joint pmfs

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

I have this problem : "Each student attending a lecture course is asked to roll a die and choose a card at random from a standard pack of playing cards. If the student rolls a 6 and chooses the Ace of Spades, they win a chocolate egg. Suppose there are 312 students in the class, what is the probability that nobody wins a chocolate egg?"

which I know how to solve but it has the following parts:

Over a period of five years, the above experiment is
conducted with a new cohort of 312 students each year.
(i) What is the probability that not a single chocolate egg is won over the
five year period?
(ii) State the distribution of the total number of chocolate eggs awarded
as prizes over the five years. Draw a sample of 20 realisations from this
distribution and present an appropriate graphical display of this sample.

For part i I did the answer in the problem to the power of 5 but I do not know what the distribution for part ii is and I don't really understand what part ii wants me to do further.

Comment: Well, what you have done amounts to computing the probability that no eggs are awarded.  What is the probability that exactly one egg is awarded?  Exactly two?  Part $ii$ is asking you to do this for each possible number of eggs.

Comment: but it says "state" the distribution. Would that be a binomial distribution with parameters n=312x5 and p=(P(X=1)P(Y=1)^5) for X being the number of 6's rolled and Y being the number of aces of spades drawn since the events are independent, or is that completely wrong?

Comment: It is certainly a binomial distribution, but I don't understand your probability.  The probability that a single event is a winner is $\frac 16\times \frac 1{52}$.

Comment: so if that is P(X=1)P(Y=1) for X~B(1,1/6) and Y~B(1,1/52), but since there are 312 students, hence 312 trials would that give X~B(312,1/6) and Y~B(312,1/52)? and do you agree with my value for n?

Comment: Yes, there are $312\times 5$ total events.  Still not sure why you are looking at $X,Y$ .  All we have here is a binomial distribution with $5\times 312$ samples and a success probability $p=\frac 16\times \frac 1{52}$ .

Comment: Yes but that is the success probability for one student, but 312 students repeat the trial so wouldn't that increase the probability of getting an egg overall? Also this is for the 5 years so whatever probability we get shouldn't that be raised to the power of 5?

Comment: No. You just have repeated, independent, trials of  a single Bernoulli process.  That process has a probability $p$ of success, so you just get a standard binomial process.  What was your answer for part $i$?

Comment: 0. I said P(no eggs won)=1-P(312 eggs are won) and P(312 eggs are won)=P(X=312)P(Y=312) for the distributions I gave above. The answer for X was 1.647441e-243 and for Y, 0, so I got 0..

Comment: But that is wrong.  Just think about it.  In any case, they are clearly after a numerical value.

Comment: I just do not understand why the chance of getting an egg is the same for 1 trial and for 312 trials..

Comment: Please read my comments again.  I never said anything like that.

Comment: I think I understand now. So let's say Z is the number of eggs won, then Z~B(312, (1/6)x(1/52))

Comment: and so the number of eggs won after 5 years, say Z1, is Z1~B(312x5, (1/6 x 1/52)^5), is that correct?

Comment: No.  There is no reason to raise $p$ to the fifth.

Comment: so then would the answer to part (i) be the same as the probability of not getting an egg in the first year? Could you explain why the probability stays the same?

Comment: I think you are just guessing here.   In all cases the binomial distribution requires the success probability of a single trial.  That's just one of the parameters of the distribution.  Please go back and study the definition of the [Binomial Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution)